# Error when making an instance of a class

Tags: c++, function, class, collision, sfml

I am working right now to make a test for collisions in sfml. However, I get an error when I run the program.

Here is my code
Edit: New Code

Main.cpp

```
#include "Collision.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML TEST");
window.setFramerateLimit(30);

sf::RectangleShape rectangle(sf::Vector2f(50, 120));
rectangle.setPosition(300, 300);

sf::View view;
view.setCenter(sf::Vector2f(300, 300));
view.setSize(sf::Vector2f(250, 250));

int moveRight = 0;
int posX;
int posY;

Collision ct();

while(window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while(window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    //movement just right for this instance

    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
    {
        moveRight = 3;
        for(moveRight; moveRight > 0; moveRight--)
        {
            rectangle.move(1, 0);
            posX = rectangle.getPosition().x;
            posY = rectangle.getPosition().y;
            if(ct.throneRoom(posX, posY) == true)
            {
                rectangle.move(1, 0);
                moveRight = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                view.move(1, 0);
            }

        }
    }

    window.setView(view);
    window.clear();
    window.draw(rectangle);
    window.display();

}
}
```

Collision.h

```
#ifndef COLLISION_H
#define COLLISION_H


class Collision
{
    public:
        Collision();
        bool throneRoom(int xPos, int yPos);
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // COLLISION_H
```

Collision.cpp

```
#include "Collision.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


Collision::Collision()
{

}

bool Collision::throneRoom(int xPos, int yPos)
{
    if(xPos > 500)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

The error I get says:

```
warning: error: request for member 'throneRoom' in 'ct', which is of non-class type 'Collision()'
```

Still have no idea what is going on.

Comment: This looks like most vexing parse: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: This question is not really properly answerable without more complete code a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be preferable, at minimum it should also include the declaration of `collisiontest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bet a nickel that you declared collisiontest as:

```
Collision collisiontest();
```

If so, that's a *function* declaration--a prototype that says collisiontest is a function with no arguments returning a Collision object.  That's what the message means by "of type Collision()".   Collision() is the type name for a function returning a Collision object, and collisiontest.throneRoom(...) is trying to treat a function name as an object of class type.

If that's the case, then simply remove the parentheses:

```
Collision collisiontest;
```

...all will be well until the next error.  :^)

Comment: Thank you sososoSOOOOOO much. I could not figure out what the problem was, and I'm doing this for the Ludum Dare so had the added pressure of time constraint. Would give you your nickel, but a +1 will have to do.

Answer (score 2):

The error message sounds as if you have declared your `collisiontest` "object" something like this (unfortunately, the code you posted doesn't show how `collisiontest` is declared):

```
Collision collisiontest();
```

However, this does **not** define an object but rather declares a function taking no argument and returning a `Collision` object (it is called the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) and stumped quite a few C++ committee members when Nicolai Josuttis first brought it up). You probably just need to remove your parenthesis:

```
Collision collisiontest;
```

This will still call the default constructor.

Comment: @Jqmfg: It still has the problem! `Collision ct();` declares a function. You want `Collision ct;`